# Android Create Class/Library to Talk to Server

Tags: java, android, performance, http-post, code-cleanup

I would like create a class or something similar I believe that is full of functions that talk to my PHP server and indirectly my MySQL database. I want to be able to access these functions from any activity or fragment in my application. The main goal is just to clean up and organize my code.

I am looking for common/standard practice or recommendations.I hate having functions declared in activities and fragments that could be more universally declared. I just learn android and java as I go as I know other programming languages, but I am working in Android Studio right now.

The functions will just performing HTTP POST/GET similiar to the javascript ajax below (obviously changed to appropriate java, I just didn't have time to write the android. I thought I'd wait until I knew where I was going to write all the functions):

```
$.ajax({
 url: 'http://www.atsocio.com/app_add.php',
 dataType: 'jsonp',
 data: {type:myType, url:myUrl, email:myEmail}, 
 success: function(data)    {
     callback(data)
 },
 error: function()  {
    callback(data)
 }    
})
```

Comment: How about a rest library like RESTDroid.  It is fairly simple to use and returns data via callback on a java object.  https://github.com/PCreations/RESTDroid  There are other similar frameworks out there, just see which is best for your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely create specific classes that are responsible for interacting with the web services.  Once you do, you can just inject/get/instantiate those objects in your Fragments and Activities to do your bidding.

As far as libraries to help with the web service interaction, I highly recommend [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)

Comment: I ended up using Retrofit. So easy. So asynchronous friendly.